# textFieldDidBeginEditing and textFieldDidEndEditing in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

how can I use the methods `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing` with the default TextField struct by apple.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`TextField` has `onEditingChanged` and `onCommit` callbacks.

For example:

```
@State var text = ""
@State var text2 = "default"
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField($text, placeholder: nil, onEditingChanged: { (changed) in
            self.text2 = "Editing Changed"
        }) {
            self.text2 = "Editing Commited"
        }
        Text(text2)
    }
}
```

The code in `onEditingChanged` is only called when the user selects the `textField`, and `onCommit` is only called when return, done, etc. is tapped.

**Edit:** When the user changes from one `TextField` to another, the previously selected `TextField`'s `onEditingChanged` is called once, with `changed` (the parameter) equaling `false`, and the just-selected `TextField`'s `onEditingChanged` is also called, but with the parameter equaling `true`. The `onCommit` callback is **not** called for the previously selected `TextField`.

**Edit 2:**
Adding an example for if you want to call a function `committed()` when a user taps return or changes `TextField`, and `changed()` when the user taps the `TextField`:

```
@State var text = ""
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField($text, placeholder: nil, onEditingChanged: { (changed) in
           if changed {
               self.changed()
           } else {
               self.committed()
           }
        }) {
            self.committed()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not called when they switch textfields.

Comment: It does. I just tested it. I'll update my answer to explain what happens when you switch `TextField`s.

Comment: no. it doesn't. I have tested it now. do you have a sample project?

Comment: @jsbeginnerNodeJS check the answer now. `onCommit` is not called on the previous `TextField` when they switch, but `onEditingChanged` is called, with its parameter equaling `false`.

Comment: @jsbeginnerNodeJS added an example for my previous edit

Comment: Is there a way to actually trigger the commit? (I need this so it runs the number formatter correctly)

Answer (score 12):

## SwiftUI 3 (iOS 15+)

Since TextField.init(_text:onEditingChanged:) is scheduled for deprecation in a future version it may be best to use @FocusState. This method also has the added benefit of knowing when the TextField is no longer the "first responder" which `.onChange(of:)` and `.onSubmit(of:)` alone will not do.

```
@State private var text = ""
@FocusState private var isTextFieldFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Text Field", text: $text)
            .focused($isTextFieldFocused)
            .onChange(of: isTextFieldFocused) { isFocused in
                if isFocused {
                    // began editing...
                } else {
                    // ended editing...
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: `@FocusState` does not react to input, so it does not make a good substitute. `.onChange(of:)` is a much more appropriated substitute. `.onSubmit(of:)` is the substitute for `.onCommit:`.

Comment: @Yrb I don't see the need to react to input here. The question is asking how to detect when the text field begins and ends edits which exactly correlates with it focus state.

Answer (score 0):

## SwiftUI 2

> ios15 and above

The syntax has changed for swiftui2
a modifier `onChange` is triggered when a property value has changed and `onSubmit` is triggered when form is submitted ie you press enter

```swift
TextField("search", text: $searchQuery)
    .onChange(of: searchQuery){ newValue in
         print("textChanged")
    }
    .onSubmit {
         print("textSubmitted")
    }
```

Comment: 'onSubmit(of:_:)' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer!

Comment: yes it is, I will put that in the description