# TextField Core Data Auto-save

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a `TextField`, that gets auto-saved to core data on any change. It's working, though it seems quite wasteful as the auto-save is done for every typed character. For example, if I type in `word`, then the auto-save is triggered 4 times (`w`, `wo`, `wor`, `word`). How could I make it recognize that I'm still typing, so it would wait for me to complete a word/sentence?

```swift
struct PostView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
    private var viewContext

    @ObservedObject
    var post: Post

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Post", text: $post.text)
            .onChange(of: post.text) {
                $0

                do {
                    try viewContext.save()
                } catch {
                    let nsError = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

EDIT: It's important that the save happens after the user stops typing and while the `TextField` is still focused.

Comment: You can use `onEditingChanged` as in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551874/8697793

Comment: Does this answer your question? [textFieldDidBeginEditing and textFieldDidEndEditing in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550881/textfielddidbeginediting-and-textfielddidendediting-in-swiftui)

Comment: It's important that the save happens after the user stops typing and while the `TextField` is still focused. `onEditingChanged` is called when the `TextField` looses focus, so it's sadly not what I'm looking for. But thanks!